# JavaScript Incremented Variable Not Read In Conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, increment

I'm writing a simple little JavaScript and that basically appends an element every time a button is clicked. I also want to limit the number of times the element can be appended via a counter and a conditional statement.

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nsz/)

The Code:

**HTML**

```
<p id="moreUpload">click me</p>
<div id="file-uploads"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var div = "<div class='fileupload fileupload-new' data-provides='fileupload'><span class='btn btn-file'><span class='fileupload-new'>Select file</span><span class='fileupload-exists'>Change</span><input type='file' name='file[]' /></span><span class='fileupload-preview'></span><a href='#' class='close fileupload-exists' data-dismiss='fileupload' style='float: none;'>x</a></div>";
var count = 1;

if (count < 6) {
    $("#moreUpload").click(function () {
        $(div).hide().appendTo("#file-uploads").fadeIn(500);
        alert(count);
        count++;
    });
}
```

Basically as written the JavaScript will allow infinite appends, I assumed incrementation was not working. However the alert calls out the number I expect to see. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try moving your condition inside of click function,because outside of click function it is doing nothing when you click button it only run inside of click events code:

```
$("#moreUpload").click(function () {
    if (count < 6) {
        $(div).hide().appendTo("#file-uploads").fadeIn(500);
        alert(count);
        count++;

    }
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nsz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#moreUpload").click(function () {
    if (count < 6) {
        console.log(count);
        $(div).hide().appendTo("#file-uploads").fadeIn(500);
        alert(count);
        count++;
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nsz/2/)

Everytime you are change the count variable.But it's on global scoop.